# What is the difference between write and respond in prolog

Tags: prolog

Based on the code I've got, there is no explicit difference between those two procedures. I can use both of them to print things I want to.

Comment: `write/1` is an ISO Prolog predicate for writing output to the terminal. `respond` is not standard Prolog. What Prolog are you using?

Comment: I use SWI-Prolog. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you share a link to the online SWI Prolog documentation that defines `respond`?

Comment: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=record

Comment: I don't see `respond` on that page